# which is better getting all the data up front or getting data on demand for an iOS App

Tags: ios

I am currently on an iOS app that has three table view controllers - Currently, I am sending HTTP request to get JSON data for from my first table view controller, then another HTTP request for my second then the third.

Is there any benefit of getting all data up front? or Getting data on demand as a user goes to each view controller.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Getting all the data up front is a better user experience but waiting is easier on their data plan. It's really your call, if the amount of data is small I would just load it in. If these "Lists" of data you are requesting require pagination (requesting more data as the user scrolls) then maybe think about waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ask yourself:

- Will the data ever get updated?
- Do all users need everything to be downloaded?
- Do all users have the same speed? If some have low speed, why not just wait till they need it?
- If you get data on demand, then likely there will be some loading time for each page. Additionally there are less chances that they could be doing something offline. Is that what you want?

The normal solution is to download the big chunk that doesn't change that often and then based on whatever average of time that you think is reasonable, make a HEAD (or maybe GET) request and find out of it has been updated or not, while you allow the much more frequent updatable parts parts

Comment: Thanks for you response

• There will be a CURD operation in each TableView Controller
• User does not need all the data upfront
• I am planning to use CoreData for offline viewing (READ ONLY), Do you think if I get all data upfront, I do not need to use CoreData when user offline as the data cached in Struct Objects.?
• Each list will have the maximum of 50 items.

Comment: say at step 1 you got all the data...then 20 steps later you reach the tableView. How do you access all that data? It has to be persisted or cached somewhere (FWIW caching and persisting data are not the same!). If you cache or persist it somewhere then you don't need coredata the caching or persisting is enough. If you don't cache or persist it then obviously you need to request it each time. Though once you've downloaded it you *can* decide to cache it or not cache that request.  See [`NSURLRequest.CachePolicy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy)